# Using jQuery UI effects when dropping items between tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable, jquery-effects

I have a jQuery UI tab control.  It contains blocks that can be sorted.  They can also be dropped on other tabs.  When a block is dropped on another tab, I want to use the slide effect to hide the block from the current tab before displaying it on the new tab.

[Here is a demonstration of the problem on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87hJ2/3/) (Follow the directions on the jsFiddle link to duplicate the problem)

The jsFiddle demo initially shows a working state for the problem.  It uses the standard .hide() method to hide a block.  But when using the "slide" effect with hide(), unexpected results occur.  The block is not animated.  Instead, after the animation interval of 1000ms the block just disappears from the tab and then is placed in an unexpected position on the new tab.

The expected behavior is that the block will slide to the left and be moved from the "Full" tab to the "Empty" tab.

Comment: Well, I kinda tried something here: http://jsfiddle.net/bm8nk/

Comment: @battal is correct. "slide" isn't a speed of .hide()

Comment: @Paul The hide method has this signature:     `hide( effect, [options], [speed], [callback] )`  See [jquery ui documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/hide/)

Comment: See here: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: I'm aware of the default jquery hide method.  This question is in regards to the jquery ui hide method.

Comment: @Paul: He is talking about jquery UI.  Different API with a different signature.